# Google Apps Script - Google Sheet - Array randomly getting cannot read property

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to read property "deviceId" from an array pulled from our google domain, deviceId exists but the script randomly stops and i get "TypeError: Cannot read property "deviceId" from undefined." This returns 48 valid results, If i set the max results to a lower number it still stops with the same error.

This also happens to all other properties i try to read.

```
function chromebookdetails() {
var domain, chromebooks, page, ss, sheet, pageToken, i
domain = "mydomainnamehere"
chromebooks= new Array()
do{
page = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list("my_customer",
{domain: domain,
maxResults: 10,
pageToken: pageToken
}) 
for (i in page.chromeosdevices){
chromebooks.push(page.chromeosdevices[i])
}
pageToken = page.nextPageToken
}while(pageToken){
var row = 1
for (var i = 0; i < chromebooks.length; i++) {
var sheetData4 = onSheet.getSheetByName("chromebook") 
sheetData4.getRange(row, 1).setValue(page.chromeosdevices[i].deviceId);
Logger.log(page.chromeosdevices[i].deviceId)
row++
Logger.log(row)
}
}
}
```

My spreadsheet named chromebook should populate one column (for now) each row having a separate chromebook device id. 
What is get is 48 results (if max results is set at 1500) (I have 848 devices in total) or 8 results (if max results is set at 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
sheetData4.getRange(row, 1).setValue(page.chromeosdevices[i].deviceId);
```

with:

```
sheetData4.getRange(row, 1).setValue(chromebooks[i] ? chromebooks[i].deviceId : "");
```

Comment: Unfortunately its the exact same error, returns 9 rows and pops up 
TypeError: Cannot read property "deviceId" from undefined., If i set max rows to 100 it gets further to row 48) but still fails, when debugging i can see the property on row 10 (or row 49)

Comment: It is likely that the deviceId is not available in your data for some items. You can add a check for that. (see updated code)

Comment: tried this and it too fails at the same row (if max results = 100 it stops at row 49, if set to 10 stops at row 9)
`if(chromebooks[i].length == 0){
    // array is empty 
    Logger.log('empty'); 
    } else {
    //array not empty
    Logger.log('not empty');
    sheetData4.getRange(row, 1).setValue(chromebooks[i].deviceId);
    }`

Comment: After much head scratching i removed the Logger entry `Logger.log(page.chromeosdevices[i].deviceId)`
and it resulted in all records being pulled, thankyou!